# Upgrade from 2003 to 2008 server

Tags: windows-server-2003

My company is undergoing upgrade from windows 2003 server environment to windows 2008 environment. Now we are trying to replace all domain controller servers to windows 2008. We want to keep the same name of the server. We are replacing the hardware itself as well so we are not doing an upgrade from 2003 to 2008 on the same server. What steps need to implement for proper installation.

Comment: For interest's sake, why is it important that the name remains the same?

Comment: Ditto.  The people who know about naming machines should know that the name doesn't matter.  Besides, nobody outside of the AD Server admins should know the DCs names; they should just reference the domain name and let the DCs figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can setup the new DCs with new names, transfer the roles, decommission the old  DCs and then rename the new ones.

However, as mentioned by other comment, it's neither necessary nor desirable to do so if these machines are only DCs. Is there any other requirements you forgot to mention ?

Answer (score -2):

This is too wide a question - a basic answer would be to shutdown one 2003 DC, build a new one with the same name/IP using 2008, bring it up, add it to the domain, test then repeat for other 2003 DCs but you'll need to ask a more specific question if you want more detail sorry.